# Is it possible to get the greatest common divisor of two numbers via calculated column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

What I'm attempting to do is create a calculated column that displays an image's aspect ratio based on the computed columns Picture Width and Picture Height.

This video (https://youtu.be/b-W64DHKO8o?t=99) does exactly what I'm looking for in Excel, but when I tried using the GCD function in SharePoint, it sent me to a technical error page.

Did I format it incorrectly, or is this even possible to do?

Here's the formula I tried:

```
=GCD([Picture Width],[Picture Height])
```

Comment: GCD function is not available in SharePoint. Functions in excel and SharePoint are different.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I have added an answer below with some explanation and link to documentation showing available functions in SharePoint formulas.

Comment: Please [accept my below response as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this SharePoint technical page error because `GCD` function in Excel formulas is not supported by SharePoint calculated column formulas.

You can find all available functions in SharePoint calculated column formulas in below Microsoft official documentation:

[Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)

You will have to utilize the functions available in above documentation to achieve your requirements based on the business logic.